# How to tell OS 10.9 to do something whenever I save in a certain application?

Tags: macos, automation, launchd

How can I automatically execute a shell command, AppleScript or launchd task whenever I "Save" within a specific application?

OS: Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer probably answers your question - [Bash script, watch folder, execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475252/bash-script-watch-folder-execute-command).

This is not far from running cron as the script sleeps for 2 seconds and recalculates MD5 hashes on files in a directory.

If you want a real event-driven solution you could try [fswatch](https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch) or any other app/lib using [FSEvent](https://github.com/search?q=fsevent).

Comment: The problem with this approach (watching a folder) is that I might want to save my file to a different folder each time or that other processes might change the content of the folder I tell FSEvent (or launchd) to watch.

Comment: Easiest way to circumvent this would be copying those files to a tmp dir where you can do transformations without the risk of getting an infinite I/O loop.

There is no easy way to hook up to an apps save event. You can try playing with [DTrace (rwbypid.d)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECDTRACETOOLS) and there watch when your app saves a file. IMHO it's too much of a hassle but if you have no way to keep a specific naming or dir structure then that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `WatchPaths` key of `launchd`. Create a job definition in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.convertToTxt</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/path/to/script</string>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
        <array>
            <string>/path/to/directory</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The tricky part is finding out *which* file has been modified. The script will be triggered every time a file is created or modified in this directory but `launchd` provides no clue which file triggered the action. Sorting the directory content by creation date (`ls -t /path/to/directory | head -1`) should do the trick in your case. Also make sure to write your converted file to another directory. Otherwise the file conversion will trigger the script again.

Comment: The problem with this approach (watching a folder instead of the save command) is that I might want to save my file to a different folder each time, or that other processes might change the content of the folder I tell launchd to watch.

Comment: Agreed. In this case `launchd` won't help you.